# Suppress "Ambiguous class resolution" warning on composer dump-autoload -o

Tags: php, deployment, composer-php, openshift

I'm in the follwoing situation:

I want to deploy a php-app via "git push" on openshift. Dependencies are resolved via composer. The composer.lock file (locking the dependencies to the specific wanted version) is part of the repository.

Dependencies are loaded using the `deploy` hook script using:

```
${PHP_DIR}/bin/php $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/composer.phar update --prefer-dist --no-dev -n
${PHP_DIR}/bin/php $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/composer.phar dump-autoload --optimize -n
```

One of the dependencies ([htmlpurifier](https://packagist.org/packages/ezyang/htmlpurifier)) is a dependency of a subdependency. During the second command (dump-autoload --optimize) an error complaining about a "Ambiguous class resolution"-warning is written to stderr(I suppose), causing the deploy to fail. Code is tested locally using unit/integration tests and proven to work, even with this erroneous package.

> remote: Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "HTML5" was found in both "/var/lib
>   /openshift/abc/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/ezyang/htmlpuri
>   fier/maintenance/PH5P.php" and "/var/lib/openshift/abc/app-
>   root/runtime/repo/vendor/ezyang/htmlpurifier/library/HTMLPurifier/Lexer/PH5P.php
>   ", the first will be used.

Is their a way to ignore this *specific* warning (e.g. an undocumented option), without ignoring all other warnings and/or messages generated by the command? Or is it possible to exclude a specific subdependency from autoload optimization to avoid the warning and let deploy succeed without ignoring all possible errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a discussion on the composer-user list this has been fixed in

https://github.com/composer/composer/commit/05d9912f97a2decf6a5c08dfa569dcf23d79b16d

If anyone else runs into this, update composer to the latest version using

```
composer selfupdate
```